# Embedded Media Field Video: Output both Video Flash Object and Video Thumbnail in Node Display?

Tags: 6, files

I would like to be able to access both the Video Flash Object, as well as the Video Thumbnail filepath from the Node Display. Please let me know if I can provide more info, not sure anything else is relevant! Thanks!

**Clarification**: Basically I want to be able to be able to output both the video with a custom resolution, and the thumbnail through an imagecache preset, from either a custom module, or within template.php. Essentially I would hope to end up with both the final video HTML and image HTML as individual objects or php variables, so I can then output them wherever I like from within the relevant node.tpl.php. I'm assuming there's a simple theme() function I can use for both of the above. The embedded video at this time can come from either Youtube/Vimeo.

Comment: can you explain the context? how would you like to be able to video object and the thumbnail path? do you need it globally, on certain nodes? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to set the video field display mode to full video under `/content/types/CONTENT_TYPE/display` then add the thumbnail via [theme_emvideo_video_thumbnail()](http://api.lullabot.com/theme_emvideo_video_thumbnail) as a variable using `themename_preprocess_node(&$vars)` in your theme's template.php -OR- print it directly in your node.tpl

The trick to `theme_emvideo_video_thumbnail(($field, $item, $formatter, $node, $no_link = FALSE, $options = array()))` is to provide all the right parameters. Especially `$options`

e.g.

```
<?php
  // code adapted from emvideo.theme.inc
  // ignore the <?php tag

  $system_types = _content_type_info();
  $field_name = 'field_video'; // the machine name of your video field

  $field = $system_types['fields'][$field_name];
  $field['widget'] = $system_types['content types'][$node->type]['fields'][$field_name]['widget']; // get CCK widget data. includes all formatting settings

  $options['return_url'] = TRUE; //return URL
  $options['raw'] = TRUE; // return image path. Otherwise node path is returned

  print theme('emvideo_video_thumbnail', $field, $node->{$field_name}[0], 'video_thumbnail', $node, FALSE, $options);
```

In template.php

```
<?php
// change MYTHEME with the theme's machine name or use phptemplate
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars->type == "mynodetype") {
    // see code above
    $vars->video_thumbnail = theme('emvideo_video_thumbnail'...);
  }
}
```

Then `<?php print $video_thumbnail; ?>` where you need it in `node.tpl.php` (-OR- use the first code block directly in the node template)

Hope it helps.